# How to convert an unformatted string to date and time in python

Tags: python, date, datetime

Say I have a 10 digit string with the first 6 digits being a date and the last 4 digits being military time.

> 1504230001

The first 2 digits are year, next 2 are month, next 2 are day. The remaining 4 digits are for military time

Desired output:

> 2015-04-23 00:01:00

Comment: what is military time? Also, what part of this is specifically the problem?

Comment: Have a look at [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `datetime.strptime()` is the way to go:

```
from datetime import datetime

time = 1504230001
time2 = datetime.strptime(str(time), '%y%m%d%H%M')

print(time2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Output:

```
2015-04-23 00:01:00
```

Comment: thanks! is there any reason for strftime(). i printed time2 directly and it's the same as calling time2.strftime()

Comment: Yes, that is the print output of the datetime object. You can settle with that if you only want to print the output. If you need a string representation of the datetime object you can assign it like this: `time_string = time2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`.